# How to inspect IFaceMap of a type using SOS debugging extension in .NET

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

Is it possible to output the IFaceMap of a type using the SOS debugging extension? The `DumpMT` command only gives the number of interfaces a type implements but it doesn't give any command to output the IFacemap entries themselves

```
 !DumpMT -MD 007938ec 
 EEClass:         00791310 
 Module:          00792e94 
 Name:            DebugTest.Customer 
 mdToken:         02000004
 BaseSize:        0x10 
 ComponentSize:   0x0 
 Slots in VTable: 10 
 Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 1
```

`!DumpHeap` also doesn't output the interfaces.

Comment: ILDasm will show all interfaces for a type. You just need to know what assembly the type is defined and name of the type. The only case where this would not work is if you generate types at run time dynamically.

Comment: @sevatitov I am looking to inspect the structures at runtime using SOS, specifically the way the Resolver resolves the call of an interface object to the final method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never came across such a functionality in SOS or SOSEX. The closest commands I saw are from [NetExt (Codeplex)](https://netext.codeplex.com). NetExt is Open Source, so if you like to look into the internals, you could read the source code to see how it finds out the interface information.

One command is `!windex -implement <InterfaceName>`. However, this does also not list all interfaces of a type, but rather the opposite: all types that implement an interface. This sounds potentially interesting for your case.

The other is `!wclass <MethodTable>` where the output looks similar like .NET decompiled code. On class definition level, you can see the implemented interfaces (excerpt from the NetExt documentation):

```
0:00> !wclass 00000001045f0c68
...
namespace System.Web.Configuration {

 internal class HttpConfigurationSystem: System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem
 {
...
```